# Нужна помощь по скрипту интсаллера

Tags: c++, linux, qt5

Пишу кроссплатформенное приложение. Запнулся на сборке инсталлера(использую `QtIFW 3.1.1`).
В файле скрипта `installscripts.qs` есть строчка:

`component.addElevatedOperation("Execute","cmd","/C","@TargetDir@\\install.bat","UNDOEXECUTE","cmd","/C","@TargetDir@\\uninstall.bat");`

Она запускает батник при удалении и установке. Батник создает записи в реестре, задает переменные среды, создает ярлыки и т.д.

Написал простой скрипт с mkdir,но все равно ошибка`неожиданный код завершения:127`.Значит что QtUFW просто не запускает баш скрипт.Как это исправить?

Comment: заменить `cmd` на `bash` и `.bat` на `.sh`?

Comment: Заменил,не работает

Comment: Так как вы не приводите в вопросе ни измененую версию, ни сообщение об ошибке, включаю свою телепатию и вижу что вы не убрали `"/C"` и не заменили `\\ ` на `/`

Comment: component.addElevatedOperation("Execute","bash","@TargetDir@/ins","UNDOEXECUTE","bash","@TargetDir@/unis.sh");.Пишет что не удалось исполнить bash /home.. . Мои скрипты без расширения .sh.Я через chmod +x сделал их исполняемыми

Comment: Ну если передавать скрипт как параметр bash, то его не обязательно делать исполняемым, но и хуже от этого не будет. Попробуйте вместо имени скрипта передать просто `--help` чтобы убедится, что bash вызывается. Если будет ошибка, попробуйте `/bin/bash`

Comment: Проблема оказалась в /bin/bash,Спасибо